# What should the maximum difference be between a float and a 16 bit calculation?

Tags: floating-point, integer, rounding, fixed-point

Lets say I have a formula that calculates a value. I can calculate the value either with floating point arithmetic or with fixed point arithmetic (using 16 bit integers).

What should be the maximum difference that I could expect due to rounding/scaling errors?

Answer (score 1):

Infinity. In general, the compounding of errors in a sequence of floating-point operations can produce any error from zero to infinity and can also produce NaN. That applies both to the error of the computed result from the ideal mathematical result and to the difference between the results computed with two different formats.

Useful limits can be given only when there is some description of the operations to be performed. There is an entire field of study for this, called [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis). If you provide the formula being calculated, including the particular way it is being calculated, some limits can usually be derived.

Comment: Given that the comparison here is between floating-point and fixed-point computation, one would also need information on the range of all inputs for the computation to derive any meaningful error bounds.